# How to unpackaged Alteryx .yxzp file into lower version

Tags: alteryx

Can anyone guide me. I have Alteryx 2019.3 version installed into my system. I have received a .yxzp file which made in higher version. How to unpackage it into lower version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .yxzp is just a zip file. Rename it to .zip and unzip it. Then check all Alteryx-related files (e.g. workflows, macros, etc) files in the extract, and update their version number using a text editor: version number will be right near the top of the file - change them to match similar file type(s) you've created yourself with your version. Then re-zip everything and change the .zip name back to .yxzp.